# шифровка в php, дешифровка в Android

Tags: php, java, android

криптую файл в php и скачиваю его на android устройство, дальше надо расшифровать.

кусок на php

```
$file = fopen('License.pdf', 'rb');
$size = filesize($file);

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=License');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');

while (!feof($file)) {
//  print ($data ^  4);
    $data = fread($file,4096);
    if (strlen($data) == 4096) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4096; $i++) {
            $data[$i] = ($data[$i] ^ $data[0]);
        }
    }
    print $data;
}
```

кусок на Java

```
BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                outFile = new File(filesDir, file.getName());
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath + "_dec_02");

                String base = null;
                String save = null;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int size;
                char helpKey = 0;
                char[] keys = key.toCharArray();
                while ((size = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    if (size == 4096) {
//
                        for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
                            buffer[i] = (byte) (buffer[i] ^ buffer[0]);
                        }
                    }
//
                    out.write(buffer);
                    out.flush();
                }
```

что делаю не так?

Comment: А кто ж вас знает что вы делаете не так, если вы даже не пишете в чем проблема...

Comment: прошу прощения :-) смысл в том что в php как бы криптую получаю файлик и естественно обратно расшифровать на Android устройстве уже не могу

Comment: В самом вопросе проблему опишите...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4096; $i++) {
   $data[$i] = ($data[$i] ^ $data[0]);
}
```

Как минимум ошибка тут: первая итерация цикла (i=0) приведет к исполнению фактически такого кода:

```
$data[0] = ($data[0] ^ $data[0]);
```

То есть, вы запишите в $data[0] ноль и продолжите "шифрование" нулем. Вряд ли вы хотели перетирать свой "ключ"...